# Выбор с исключающим условием

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задача: Выбрать тех изготовителей (табл. "Product", поле "maker"), которые производят ПК (табл. "PC") **но, при этом**, не производят Лэптопы (табл. "Laptop"). Схема БД тут: 
[image: Схема]

Ваши варианты?

Comment: А где ваши варианты?

Comment: Решил не писать, так как они все не подошли, да и не уверен в правильности подхода.

Comment: Вы нарушаете правила сайта www.sql-ex.ru

Comment: @msi, а при чем тут этот сайт? Или это такая реклама?

Comment: @visman, потому что задача взята оттуда: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#apx1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно:

```
select distinct p.maker
from product p
inner join pc on p.model = pc.model
where p.model NOT in (select distinct l.model from laptop l)
```

А вообще, странная связь у таблиц - по названию модели.

Comment: Да, странная, но задача учебная, так что ничего удивительного. Примерно так же делал, результат неверный. Ваш тоже проверил.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, разгадка нашлась, все дело было скорее в понимании сути вопроса, чем в реализации. Итак, разгадка следующая

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
FROM Product
WHERE type = 'PC' AND 
      maker NOT IN (SELECT maker 
                    FROM Product 
                    WHERE type = 'Laptop'
                    )
```

Дело в том, что из-за нелогичной структуры БД, я воспринял вопрос "Find out the makers that sell PCs but not laptops" как "Какие производители производят ПК но не Лаптопы", но в пояснении указали, что таблица Products относится к продажам, а уже Лаптопы и ПК к спецификациям товаров. Вот так вот, будьте внимательны и ищите подвох.

Мой вариант (если оставить вопрос как понял его я сначала) был таков:

```
select distinct p.maker
from product p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PC 
              WHERE p.model = PC.model)

Except

select distinct p.maker
from product p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Laptop 
              WHERE p.model = Laptop.model)
```

Он возвращал тоже верный результат, но методологически был неверен.

Всем спасибо, будьте внимательны.

Comment: ну так отметьте ответ от Qwertiy как верный - он полностью отвечает на вопрос в том виде, в котором вы его сформулировали. "надо было  догадаться что я неправильно перевел с английского" - это не ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash ...да это и не английский был :-) ибо фраза _Find out the makers that sell PCs but not laptops_ – яркий пример бессмысленного и беспощадного рязанского английского. "find out", "makers" - хахаха))